# How to detect when to use radix sort in runtime

Tags: sorting, performance, c++, radix-sort

I'm implementing a stable integer sorting algorithm, I've chosen radix sort. I've tested LSD vs MSD implementation, wrote MSD/LSD hybrid implementation to reduce bandwidth pressure. The repo is here: https://github.com/KirillLykov/int-sort-bmk

Now some Figures to discuss.

First of all, radix sorts outperform significantly stable_sort on shuffled unique values in the range 0..N, where N is number of elements in the array:

[image: Sorting shuffled unique values in the range 0..N]

On an input of randomly generated (uniform) numbers in the range 0..1e9, LSD outperforms other sorting algorithms, but MSD doesn't:

[image: Sorting uniformly distributed values in the range 0..1e9]

I don't have a good explanation for the last observation.
But it hinted to develop a combined radix sort implementation which will rely on MSD first and when the size of the range is smaller than `2^14` use LSD.

I've benchmarked these implementations on different distributions:

[image: Performance of different sorting algorithms on various distributions]

Observation is that although radix sort outperforms on random data, it performs poorly on some specific cases.

I think that a good approach is to define a criterium when/when-not use radix sort depending on the input data.
This approach was implemented in `boost::spreadsort` -- knowing the size of the input, min/max values they make a decision whether to use bucket sort one more time or to rely on another sorting algorithm. See for example [boost::spread_sort implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/sort/blob/develop/include/boost/sort/spreadsort/detail/integer_sort.hpp#L189)
Probably, it is possible to adapt the same analysis for radix sort yet not sure because I couldn't reverse engineer the the math behind these checks (I've read the [report](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/sort/doc/papers/original_spreadsort06_2002.pdf)).

So the question is you have any ideas on how to develop criterium for using other sorting algorithms based on some (cheap to compute) observations about the input data?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your MSD and LSD radix sorts are doing quite different things. For example, your LSD is non-recursive and your MSD is recursive, and recursive calls are costlier than you think in practice. (Try an explicit stack; you will be shocked by the time difference.)

Don't forget to fall back to insertion sort for small ranges, just like you would with quick sort. (Yes, insertion sort is stable.)